# civibooking fatal error -- need suggestions

Tags: civibooking

I'm running Drupal 7.9, CiviCRM 5.50.1 and php 7.4 and am getting this error with CiviBooking:

```
Fatal error: Cannot make static method CRM_Contact_BAO_Query_Interface::from() non static in class CRM_Booking_BAO_Query in /home/mysite/www/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/civi_extensions/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.booking/CRM/Booking/BAO/Query.php on line 270
```

I am not a PHP guru. Can someone explain what is wrong? And maybe a bit on how I might fix it?

The code starting at line 270 is:

```
function from($name, $mode, $side) {
    $from = NULL;
    switch ($name) {
      case 'civicrm_booking':
        $from = " $side JOIN civicrm_booking ON civicrm_booking.primary_contact_id = contact_a.id AND civicrm_booking.is_deleted = 0 ";
        break;
      case 'civicrm_booking_status':
        $from = " $side JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_booking_status ON (option_group_booking_status.name = 'booking_status') ";
        $from .= " $side JOIN civicrm_option_value civicrm_booking_status ON (civicrm_booking.status_id = civicrm_booking_status.value AND option_group_booking_status.id = civicrm_booking_status.option_group_id ) ";
        break;
      case 'civicrm_booking_payment_status':
        $from .= " $side JOIN civicrm_booking_payment on civicrm_booking_payment.booking_id = civicrm_booking.id ";
        $from .= " $side JOIN civicrm_contribution contribution on contribution.id = civicrm_booking_payment.contribution_id ";
        $from .= " $side JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_booking_payment ON option_group_booking_payment.name = 'contribution_status' ";
        $from .= " $side JOIN civicrm_option_value civicrm_booking_payment_status ON (contribution.contribution_status_id = civicrm_booking_payment_status.value AND option_group_booking_payment.id = civicrm_booking_payment_status.option_group_id ) ";
        break;
      case 'civicrm_booking_associated_contact':
        $from = " $side JOIN civicrm_contact civicrm_booking_associated_contact ON (civicrm_booking_associated_contact.id = civicrm_booking.secondary_contact_id) ";
        break;
    }
    return $from;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

That changed as part of civigrant changes in 5.47. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/adde8f5eb1443a5048e5bf01dcb3fb7035fe557c#diff-b48ef419b5be8483fd4f9d6eaba0a30e7ae575001b25d554bef4331724518699R32

Just put the word static in front of line 270, i.e.

`public static function from`...

Comment: and open an issue / PR on civibooking?

Answer (score 2):

We have been using [forked repo](https://github.com/pradpnayak/civibooking), it has fatal error fixes.

Comment: Thank you, thank you Demerit and Pradeep. So grateful for your time to respond.